# I cannot type a lowercase letter K in Ubuntu Mate on Lenovo P50

Tags: keyboard, xorg, lenovo, mate

This is by far the strangest bug I have ever seen. I'm in the process of configuring a fresh installation of Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on a Lenovo P50 Laptop. I'm unable to type a lowercase `'K'`. Uppercase worKs fine, as do compose Key combinations involving the letter, but I cannot type it in lowercase.

Now, `xev` picKs up lowercase `K` Keypresses thusly:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 78, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
root 0x271, subw 0x0, time 584185, (115,103), root:(117,164),
state 0x0, keycode 45 (keysym 0x6b, k), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6b) "k"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Compared to other lowercase Key presses (e.g. `b`):

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
root 0x271, subw 0x0, time 620761, (145,166), root:(147,256),
state 0x0, keycode 56 (keysym 0x62, b), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I presume that the missing `XmbLookupString` for lowercase `K` is the culprit, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: When you press "k", does the letter not appear, i.e. does it leave the space empty, or does the cursor not even move forward?

Comment: I checKed, cursor does not move forward. No input is generated.

Comment: Indeed, this is _truly_ strange. But: Make sure that you have no keyboard shortcuts for "k" defined, either in the "Keyboard shortcuts" utility or elsewhere, such as in the Compiz Settings Manager (if you have it installed). What did you do before the problem started, which might have caused this ?

Comment: @JonasCz: Yes, it is liKely something of that nature. The last thing I did before the problem started was turn on Xcompose. I've already tried turning it off, it didn't reverse the issue. I'll go hunting.

Comment: Nothing bound to `k` in Compiz (its the "Commands" option right?), nor in Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Got it! Well, that's embarrassing. I'd copied the ~/.XCompose file from another machine and it got corrupted in the transfer,  binding something to `k`. I thought I'd disabled XCompose but was mistaken.

Comment: What are the AskUbuntu rules for "egregious user errors"? Should I delete this or just leave it out there?

Comment: @MRule Good that you solved it! Please write up your findings as an answer. Even egregious user errors are bound to happen sometimes, and perhaps the answer will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be classified as "user error", but it may be worth noting what happened:

1. I transferred an `.XCompose` file from another machine and it became corrupted in the process. This caused a broken key configuration to get bound to 'k'
2. I thought that it was necessary to invoke the command `export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` to activate a user-defined `.XCompose` file, because this was once the case in Gnome. Therefore, during debugging I though I'd disabled the user-defined key bindings by removing this command from `.gnomerc`, but had not. This lead me to (erroneously) believe something more complicated was happening.

Similar errors in the future could be avoided by having X validate the `~/.XCompose` and rejecting incorrectly formatted key-bindings.